# Server still ask for password after ssh-copy-id

Tags: users, password, sshd, authentication, ssh-keygen

I copied my SSH public key to a server using ssh-copy-id, but the server still ask for a password.
I checked the permission on the files in the ssh folder and they are readable for user only. I also checked the sshd_config file and the PasswordAuthentication line ends with yes.
I checked the authorized_keys file on the server and the key matches the key I have in my id_rsa.pub.

I run

```
ssh -i <path_to_key> <myusername@host> -vvv
```

and this is part of the error I got (StackExchange won't let me add all of it) -

```
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
.....
debug1: Connecting to <host> port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to <host>:22 as <myusername>
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/users/studs/bsc/2016/orelhaz/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /users/studs/bsc/2016/orelhaz/.ssh/known_hosts:119
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from <host>
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
.......
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/users/studs/bsc/2016/orelhaz/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /users/studs/bsc/2016/orelhaz/.ssh/known_hosts:119
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from <host>
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/users/studs/bsc/2016/orelhaz/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /users/studs/bsc/2016/orelhaz/.ssh/known_hosts:119
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 132.72.44.112
debug1: Host <host> is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /users/studs/bsc/2016/orelhaz/.ssh/known_hosts:119
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
......
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-keyex
debug3: remaining preferred: gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-keyex
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
...........
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: KEYRING:persistent:8108)

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: KEYRING:persistent:8108)

debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

Thanks.

Comment: Add the output of `ssh username@machine` to the question. Also, does the config on the machine have `PubkeyAuthentication yes`?

Comment: when I run ssh username@machine it's just ask for my password. I opened the ssh_config file on the remote machine but it only have - "GSSAPIAuthentication yes".

Comment: not the same thing!

Comment: According to the debug output, ssh offered the id_rsa key to the server and the server didn't accept it. If you check the syslogs on the remote server, you might find that the sshd process logged the reason why it didn't accept the key.

Comment: Does the config file actually have `PubkeyAuthentication yes`? If so, are you sure that `ssh-copy-id` actually worked?

Comment: The config file on the remote server doesn't have ```PubkeyAuthentication yes```, and I don't have permissions to change it. Is it necessary?

Comment: Yes. Whoever has the ability to change it needs to do so and then restart the `sshd` service.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you are using the correct key file specification? Compare your above debug log to mine:

```
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:6wZNjCyUdVXcrf05PJaayPZ0iB/0052zDvA+luvO0JM
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:6wZNjCyUdVXcrf05PJaayPZ0iB/0052zDvA+luvO0JM
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:6wZNjCyUdVXcrf05PJaayPZ0iB/0052zDvA+luvO0JM
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using ssh-rsa SHA256:6wZNjCyUdVXcrf05PJaayPZ0iB/0052zDvA+luvO0JM
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
```

You see that the public key offered has a full path (the one it was created in and actually resides) specified, as opposed to your's which is just a filename. Mayhap check your local config (keyword: `IdentityFile`)?

Comment: I tried with the full path but I still get the same problem. But thanks anyway